# Alignment in Itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I need help in alignment while creating a pdf using itextsharp. The document number and the creation date should appear in the same line. but the doc number should ne left aligned and the date should be right aligned. Is it possible?

Comment: did you check this: http://jwcooney.com/2014/01/04/itextsharp-pdfpcell-text-alignment-example/

Comment: Thanks Chris...it worked like charm..